# File Command 108k files: Too Many Args

Tags: linux, file, find, ksh

I have a directory that has 108k files in it. 
I am using the KSH shell on RHEL5

```
ls *
-dash_bin_ksh: ls: /bin/ls: cannot execute [Argument list too long]
```

Only command that seems to work is the find command.

```
find .
file 1
file 2 
file n
```

I tried using find with then exec option to run the file command but I am not getting anywhere.

```
find . -exec file {}
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

What am I missing? I just want to run the file command on every file in this directory and output to a file_output.txt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For find's exec, you have to end the argument with with `\;`

You can also try:

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 file
```

xargs works by taking its STDIN and adding each element (line or delimited string) as an argument to the given executable to be executed as few times as possible. The argument list is split by --max-chars (Platform dependent upto 128Kib) into groups for execution.

`-print0` adds null chars instead of new lines which makes it safe for file names with spaces. `-0` on `xargs` is used to recognise null chars.

`-print0` and `-0` are GNU extensions and can be dropped for non GNU environments at the cost of versatility.

xargs also has the `-I` option which makes it work more like `find -exec` where the executable is run for each element.

Thanks to @glennjackman for his in-depth knowledge on this subject.

Comment: This is going to be the same problem

Comment: @jordanm, no, this will work. This is exactly what xargs is for: execute the command repeatedly for subsets of the original large list.

Comment: This does require the GNU implementation of find and xargs

Comment: @jordanm I've checked this with 300K files and can replicate the problem with `ls *` and but does work with `find . | xargs ls`

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks for the input. I've updated the answer with your points. However, in the given example, `file` is only execute once rather than repeatedly which uses the `-I` flag.

Comment: @Fuzzyfelt, file executes once with 108000 arguments? really?

Comment: @glennjackman good point, I've just looked into why this works with xargs and now see what you meant by "subsets of the original". Again, will correct to reflect your input. Thanks, again :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a `\;` to the end of your command, e.g. `find . -exec file {} \;`